# Count number of rows to generate a certain number of tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have something which allows the user to add tabs and take away tabs... however how would I go about generating the default number of tabs based on data from my sql database. For example if they were 4 rows with the same id in the id filed, it would generate 4 tabs as there is 4 rows with the same id.

here is the tab thing I found.

```
<script>
$(function() {

var total_tabs = 0;



    // initialize first tab

    total_tabs++;

    addtab(total_tabs);



    $("#addtab, #litab").click(function() {

    total_tabs++;

    $("#tabcontent p").hide();

    addtab(total_tabs);

    return false;

    });


    function addtab(count) {

    var closetab = '<a href="" id="close'+count+'" class="close">&times;</a>';

       $("#tabul").append('<li id="t'+count+'" class="ntabs">Session      '+count+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+closetab+'</li>');

       $("#tabcontent").append('<p id="c'+count+'">Tab Content '+count+'</p>');


       $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");

       $("#t"+count).addClass("ctab");



       $("#t"+count).bind("click", function() {

        $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");

        $("#t"+count).addClass("ctab");

        $("#tabcontent p").hide();

        $("#c"+count).fadeIn('slow');

       });



       $("#close"+count).bind("click", function() {

        // activate the previous tab

        $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");

        $("#tabcontent p").hide();
        $(this).parent().prev().addClass("ctab");

        $("#c"+count).prev().fadeIn('slow');



        $(this).parent().remove();

        $("#c"+count).remove();

        return false;

     });

      }

  });

  </script>


 <ul id="tabul">
 <li id="litab" class="ntabs add"><a href="" id="addtab">Add tab + </a></li>
 </ul>
```

Thanks James

Comment: This looks more like just js/jquery and not PHP, at lest based on the code provided.

Comment: yeah true but I assumed it would involve php/sql since connecting to the database

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9053970/674700), Basically, you have to follow the same principle.
Then, call `addtab(rowId)` in a `for` loop by using the returned data from your database.

Still not sure what you meant by rows with the same ID, though.

Comment: Thanks i shall check it out :)

Comment: I can make sense of some of that but fairly new to php, I shall keep at it.