# Populate HTML loaded form from PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

I have read many posts here and on other sites where they explain how to read a MySQL database and show the data on an HTML form.  The problem with all that information is that the examples build the form withing the PHP.  Mine already exists and already loaded.

My HTML/PHP:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Alpaga Wasi - Facture</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=windows-1252" >
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet_Invoice.css"/>  
    <style>
        @media print
        {
        input.Button {display:none;}
        button.Button {display:none;}
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="InvoiceViewFunction.php" method="post">
<?php include("InvoiceForm.php"); ?>
<input class="Button" type="submit" value="Get Invoice" name="nGetInvoice"/>    
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The `<?php include("InvoiceForm.php"); ?>` line brings the HTML that contains the table,tr,td and all the input fields.  This way I can reuse the same "InvoiceForm" for both inputing data into the database and retrieving it.

Here is my test code I have so far to get the data from the database when the user clicks the "Get Invoice" button.

```
<?php
//Connect to database
include("../ConfigFiles/ConnectDB_local_i.php");

    //Populating the variables
    $InvoiceNo = $_POST["nInvoiceNo"];

    //Reading a specific invoice from DB
        echo "<br>Trying to read from DB with invoice = <br>" . $InvoiceNo . "<br>"; //This tells the correct number just fine.

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `invoicedata_table` WHERE InvoiceNo = '$InvoiceNo'";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
        if($result->num_rows > 0) 
        {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
                echo stripslashes($row['ClientName']) . "<br>"; 
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            echo 'NO RESULTS';  
        }

//Close the DB connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

I am still pretty new at programming in general.  The above code works just fine to test that my SQL worked fine.  However, I don't want the data to simply echo to a new blank screen.  I want it to populate the form where I clicked the "Get Invoice" button.  I don't want to rebuild it within the PHP unless you experts can tell me it is the common way to do things.  Should I be putting my SELECT somewhere else, like client side javascript?  There are 41 fields to populate?

Comment: You should look into ajax. Basically, javascript will make a request to another php file and return the data asynchronously.

Comment: Hi AustinAllover, I briefly looked this over on w3schools.com.  I am already in over my head with the various languages HTML, CSS, Javascript, SQL.  This Ajax seems to include all of those mixed together.  I am hoping to find something a lot more simpler.

Comment: It's really simple if you use a javascript library like jQuery.

Comment: Do you need to show the form filled with its fields values? am i saying it right?

Comment: If you don't want to use ajax then you need to have form submit action same as the first html/php file you have provided but with lots of conditions that data is present or not. It's better to use jquery ajax as suggested by @AustinAllover

Comment: Okay.  I found this page (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) that seems to show a simple enough example to understand Ajax.  But I can't how it posts its data back to the form.  It builds the table.  Maybe I haven't understood how it works yet.  I will look at javascript library next.  Not sure what that is either.

Comment: check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: I was just looking at a similar page (http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp).  If I understand correctly, I create a function similar to a javascript one within my original html.  Inside it I put the $.get function that calls my file.php which contains the SQL.  This function also includes a "callback???" I guess this is how the data returns to the html but I don't understand how to get the data out of the "callback".  Am I on the right track?

Comment: I think I may have found an example that is close enough to what I want and seems easy to modify to my needs.  It is (http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107).  This was reference in another stackoverflow post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053853/retrieving-data-with-jquery-ajax-and-php-from-a-mysql-database).  I'll try working on this tomorrow.  Thank you for your help on getting me on the right track AustinAllover.  I am a bit overwhelmed but I think I should be able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Answer as per OP :

- Create a php script to receive http requests and fetch data from the database

  1. Create a php script called api.php on your server
  2. Copy and paste the example below and save it:

.

```
<?php 
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Example php script for fetching data from mysql database
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "root";
  $pass = "root";

  $databaseName = "ajax01";
  $tableName = "variables";

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 1) Connect to mysql database
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  include 'DB.php';
  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 2) Query database for data
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");          //query
  $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                          //fetch result    

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 3) echo result as json 
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

- Create a client script to fetch data from the API script using JQuery AJAX

  1. Create a html script called client.php in the same directory with the following content in it:

.

```
<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Example client script for JQUERY:AJAX -> PHP:MYSQL example
---------------------------------------------------------------------------->

<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1) Create some html content that can be accessed by jquery
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------->
  <h2> Client example </h2>
  <h3>Output: </h3>
  <div id="output">this element will be accessed by jquery and this text replaced</div>

  <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  $(function () 
  {
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 2) Send a http request with AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'api.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
      data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                                       //for example "id=5&parent=6"
      dataType: 'json',                //data format      
      success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
      {
        var id = data[0];              //get id
        var vname = data[1];           //get name
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // 3) Update html content
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname); //Set output element html
        //recommend reading up on jquery selectors they are awesome 
        // http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
      } 
    });
  }); 

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer put up only for reference, it is from [here](https://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107).